# how to create spring project?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

Can anyone please tell me, what is the best way to create a project using spring and hibernate. I have two choices : create dynamic web project and then inject spring jars OR create spring project using STS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create either way.
Either create Spring project from the beginning where you create various files, set build path's, set up pom, generate Web Descriptor file etc from scratch, or you can directly create Spring project in STS which will save some time as you do not have to create those things from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
the problem is when I want to create it in sts it generates a lot of files that I don't need, and that I don't even understand what are they used for

Comment: Yes, that is actually meant for those guys who know basics clearly.
You just start from beginning.
I myself faced the same issue few months ago. Then i benefited myself from Kevin Bowersox Spring MVC video tutorials.

Comment: ah ok. Can you please give me a link of those videos ?

Comment: I would also recommend to take a look at Spring Boot, since that is the way people should work with Spring nowadays. And there is a nice Spring Starter Wizard in STS that lets you pick the Spring Boot starters and creates a project with exactly those dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to create project from STS using available templates. If you are completely novice, you should use Spring Boot instead. Spring boot has starters for different DBs and you can use one of in-memory or file based DBs such as H2 or HSQL or Derby. To create a spring boot project goto http://start.spring.io/ and select the tools dependencies you want and then download the zip file of your project. Import this as mave/gradle project using eclipse or whatever IDE you use and run main method of your application class.

Comment: This isn't bad advise, but you don't actually have to go to 'start.spring.io' because there is a wizard inside of STS that integrates with the start.spring.io service. This saves you the hassle of downloading a zip and importing it. The wizard does all of that for you. This wizard can be opened via menu "New >> Spring Starter Project".

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you would be to take a look at the [Spring Getting Started Guide](https://spring.io/guides). Type 'data' in the search box and look through some of the guides that get suggested.

I didn't immediately see one that helps with Hybernate in particular. But since spring really 'abstracts' the specific mechanism you use to access and persist data, the [guide for JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) or [JDBC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) probably will help you on your way.

There is also a wizard included inside of STS that gives you direct access to these Guides and can import the contents of their sample code into your workspace as a project. You can open this wizard from the menu "New >> Import Getting Started Content".

PS: The answer given by Ejaz Ahmed may also help you. The 'start.spring.io' wizard and site let you get started with pom or build.gradle that has specific dependencies. Unfortunately that wizard mainly just sets up the dependencies for you. This is a big help, but it won't help you with actually writing the code that actually uses those dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC,
Spring STS is the easiest way. Since this has some inbuilt set up which makes spring configuration easy.
You can check here http://www.javavni.com/spring---environment-set-up.html to check step by step process to create new spring project.